# How to populate spinner data from ArrayList<String> in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner

Here is how I try to use ArrayList data to provide data for spinner [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRgcr.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this Helps.

```
  private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter;
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);
```

Comment: Thank a lot.. You Made This;-) @Dipali shah:-)

Comment: sorry @Dipali shah.. Again it seems give some error like                     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,CityService.city);            where City is     public static ArrayList<String> city;

Comment: Actually It required <Java.lang.Charseq> and found <Java.Lang.String> while set adapter

Comment: **ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter**; this my definition and   using **adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);**  where city is **    public static ArrayList<String> city;**

Comment: Working good.. Thanks a lot @Dipali shah

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like `mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city)`